# expression to check if barcode input exists in which case load data for that barcode else continue to create new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I'm using Access 2007 and i am doing a program to enter stock items.

I am using a form and i need to make sure that when the user inputs the barcode of the product the system checks in the table if this exists. If it does exists, i need to load data for this existing item into the 3 additional fields in the same form, otherwise to continue creating the new record.

Now i am trying to use set tempvar in the beforeupdate however i cannot get it right.

any suggestions please.

field name : [barcode]
table to look into is "cartridge static data"
additional fields to fill if barcode exists are : [cartridge] , [end user] , [phone no]

Appreciate any help

regards

Tony

Answer (score 0):

I would insert a combo box using the Access wizzard.

Select the data from "cartridge static data" i.e. [barcode] [cartridge] [end user] [phone no]

Do not hide the first row, and make sure you can see the data width in the wizard as you build it.

When completed go to the combo [data] [row source] and click the three {…}

Check what is displayed ~ for example sort by Barcode, remove nulls etc.

If you have the column widths wrong you can change those in the [format tab].

Column headers default to No which may need changing or you may be happy with that.

Under [other] name check you have a sane name e.g. cbo_barcode_search

Now attach this code to the AfterUpdate property of the Combo Box:

```
Sub cbo_barcode_search_AfterUpdate ()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    If Not IsNull(Me.cbo_barcode_search) Then
        'Save before move.
        If Me.Dirty Then
            Me.Dirty = False
        End If
        'Search in the clone set.
        Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
        rs.FindFirst "[BarCode] = " & Me.cbo_barcode_search
        'rs.FindFirst "[BarCode] = """ & Me.cbo_barcode_search & """" 'for text
        If rs.NoMatch Then
            'Trigger new form or add the just typed data into your form as required
            ‘e.g. me.field1 = cbo_barcode_search.column(0)  ' Barcode
        Else
            'Display the found record in the form.
            ' Usually use  Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark  but your question suggests this is not what you want so

            'NOTE:  First column data is column(0) NOT column(1)
            me.field1 = cbo_barcode_search.column(0)  ' Barcode
            me.field2 = cbo_barcode_search.column(1)  ' Cartridge
            me.field3 = cbo_barcode_search.column(2)  ' end user
            me.field4 = cbo_barcode_search.column(3)  ' phone no
        End If
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

You will need to modify this to match your field names (eg me.field1 is probably me.barcode but it may be me.str_barcode ~ I don't know what you used.

Hope this gets you on the right track.  Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, appreciate your reply. i will try this later in the day and let you know the outcome. truly appreciated. Tony